# Print out values in column depending on key length

Tags: c

I have the following code and would like it to print out plainText and cipherText out in a column depending on my key length.

E.g. in the example below, the key length is 7, so I would like it to print out the result in columns of 7.

```
int main(){
  char* text = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
  char* key = "pangram";
  char* cipherText = Encipher(text, key, '-');
  char* plainText = Decipher(cipherText, key);
  printf("\nKey = %s",key );
  printf("\nPlain text = %s",plainText);
  printf("\nEncipher = %s",cipherText);
  printf("\n");
}
```

So the result might look like this, but for `The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog`:

```
a t t a c k p 
o s t p o n e 
d u n t i l t 
w o a m x y z
```

My full code is available here: https://repl.it/repls/ShoddyPiercingDemos.

Comment: Please provide your [mre] completely here. If none of the linked code is actually part of the MRE then please remove the unneeded link.

Comment: I think you can reduce your MRE to something outputting a string from a char-pointer and then ask about how to spit it rigorosly into lines of a certain length.

Comment: Are you aware of the more subtle features printf provides via format specifier? If yes please elaborate the obstacles you encounter. If not please read up.

Comment: the posted link is to code that we cannot copy paste to our editor.  That is unacceptable.  Please post your code into the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `strlen()` to calculate the length of `key` and `cipherText` and then use a simple loop to print the values.

Put this at the end of your `main()` to see the results:

```c
  size_t keylen = strlen(key);
  size_t cipherLen = strlen(cipherText);

  for (size_t i = 0; i < cipherLen; i++) {
    if (i % (keylen - 1) == 0)
      printf("%c\n", cipherText[i]);
    printf("%c ", cipherText[i]);
  }
```

Output:

```
h k   m r a -
- u o   o e d
d -   b o s t
t y - i w j v
v   o - e   f
f p   z - T c
c n u e l g q
q r x   h   -
-
```